# encrypt with public key

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

I trying to use RSA encryption beetween C# and PHP server
I have public/private key generated by php  server

I have writing this in C#

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\user.ofPC\\Desktop\\priv1024.key");
    PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(reader);
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)pemReader.ReadObject();
    AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey = keyPair.Private;
    RSA rsa2 = DotNetUtilities.ToRSA((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)privateKey);
    string xmlRsa = rsa2.ToXmlString(true);
    Debug.WriteLine(xmlRsa);
    Debug.WriteLine("------------------fin");


    var RSA = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    RSA.FromXmlString(xmlRsa);

    byte[] machainechiffre = RSA.Encrypt(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(@"Texte secret Provenant de C#"), false);
    string EncryptedString = Convert.ToBase64String(machainechiffre);
    Debug.WriteLine(EncryptedString);
    Label1.Text = EncryptedString;
}
```

It's work
and when I use EncryptedString in php , I manage decrypted this string

```
<?PHP
$privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private(file_get_contents("./priv1024.key"));
$publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents("./public1024.key"));
echo"<font red color='red'>";
$encryptedData=base64_decode("pj6y+qbCZM6arWYecOXGlnhziQg0w2BxzrmVJx4SV/28REzAV8hoQk/YtpWps7CNThgHdOhiEKYw8rHdP1TOjA0PsId2a2RPPx8MfywtGMQLUzj46gjTryvgGbuGb2EvNmrGvVaA/zgGCOPRDsbjW0S4fqQc2G2yldnKLfbACc0=");
openssl_private_decrypt($encryptedData, $plainTextData, $privateKey);
echo "<br /><br />Decrypted data using private key are : <br /> ";
echo $plainTextData;
echo "<br /><br />";
echo"</font>";
?>
```

But when I use in C# my public key , it does not work

I understand that I made

I encrypt with private key of php server and I use the same private key to decrypt it
It's crazy, I know ...
How Can I use public key into C#?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private key?

Comment: yes , It's my problem. I try to use only "./public1024.key"  file (in my C# code) but it's does work 
In my mind , I get the public key (in PEM from) and I use it to encrypt my data (to send them to php server)